# smime sign and id-aa-signingCertificateV2

Tags: openssl, signing, electronic-signature

I am using openssl to sign files using a security token The command that I use is

```
OpenSSL> smime -md sha256 -nodetach -binary -outform DER -sign -signer my.pem -inkey id_XXXXXXXX -keyform engine -in test.txt -out test.p7m -engine pkcs11
```

and it works. The application that I use to verify the signature says that the signature is good, but that the  `id-aa-signingCertificateV2` is missing. I tried to google, and I discovered that this attribute is mandated by the CADES (CMS Advanced Electronic Signatures) specs.

My questions are:

- Is this attribute supported by openssl?
- If yes, how should I change the command?
- If not, what can I use to do it instead of openssl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying to ask on openssl-users and getting no answer, I found the answer on my own.

openssl currently lacks this feature, but it is possible to implement it. I sent a [patch](http://marc.info/?l=openssl-dev&m=137945559716089&w=2) to openssl-dev, which implements it for smime. I hope to get feedback and have the patch merged in the future.

Comment: HI Ottavio. Could you reach me on skype? I have similar problem urgnetly!

Comment: Ciao Giuseppe, drop me an email.